# how to programmatically hide or delete extra cell and seperators in tableview swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

In my app I have a `UITableView` with 5 cell data. When I will run the app. It will display 5 cells with data properly in Output. But there are many extra cell show empty. I want to remove extra cell in `UITableView`. I have also done in objective-C but I need some help in Swift 2.2 also I'm new in swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your `viewDidLoad()` add this line :

```
yourtableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

or use

```
 yourtableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be arising from the fact that you are specifying a greater number of rows in the `UITableView` than required  to populate data. Assuming you are populating the `UITableView` from an Array, you should probably set the row count to the count of array.

If you are using a `UITableViewController` override this method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return yourArray.count

}
```

If a `UITableView` is embedded in the `UIViewController` set `UITableView` delegate to self and implement this method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. May be this is helpful to you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

write this code

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate method like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
```